# Arguments of a keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

Say I have a user-defined keyword with some arguments:

```
*** Keywords ***
Add
  [Arguments]    ${foo}  ${bar}=${42}
  [return]       ${${foo} + ${bar}}
```

No in a python context, I have a dictionary of arguments and want to use it to call the keyword:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def foo():
    args = {'foo' : 0}
    BuiltIn.run_keyword("Add", args) # does not work, of course
```

This approach fails because robot expects arguments as a list (either named or ordered correctly). I cannot simply pass all arguments as a list here, because robot will not ignore arguments that are not declared in the keyword.

What I need to do is to

- Lookup the keyword
- Iterate over its arguments
- Create the argument list from the dictionary

Is that possible with the python API?

Answer (score 0):

You want [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) `*` for lists and `**` for dicts:

```
def my_func(a, b, c='c', d='d'):
    print(a, b, c, d)

my_func('a', 'b')
>> a b c d

my_list = ['A', 'B']
my_dict = {'c': 'C', 'd': 'D'}
my_func(*my_list, **my_dict)
>> A B C D
```